# UIWebView load problems but Safari works fine

Tags: uiwebview, load

UIWebView fails to load a web page (ex:http:/www.ncm.com), but Safari loads it fine.
It reports a tag mismatch and only loads half the page. But Safari and other browser 
handle the content correctly?

Is UIWebView faulty?